# PyQGIS script to merge vectors from a directory won't work

Tags: pyqgis, merge

I've run the command manually and compared it to what my code prints on input and I can't figure out why this isn't working. Can anyone see the error?

```
import glob, 
import os 
import processing

path = "/Users/me/dir/"
os.chdir(path)
filelist = []
for fname in glob.glob("clip_" + "*.shp"):
    uri = path + fname
    filelist.append(uri)

fileliststring = ','.join(filelist)

processing.run("native:mergevectorlayers",
{'LAYERS': "[" + fileliststring + "]", 
'CRS':None,
'OUTPUT': path + "merged.shp",})
```

When I `print(fileliststring)` the string is identical to the file format/names as far as I can tell. The error I get is:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python3.7/code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 13, in <module>
  File "/Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/tools/general.py", line 106, in run
    return Processing.runAlgorithm(algOrName, parameters, onFinish, feedback, context)
  File "/Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/core/Processing.py", line 137, in runAlgorithm
    raise QgsProcessingException(msg)
_core.QgsProcessingException: Unable to execute algorithm
Incorrect parameter value for LAYERS
```

Answer (score 4):

Your are getting this error because of wrong input type of the `fileliststring` variable which is a `str`.

```
print(type(fileliststring)) #<class 'str'>
```

However, it must be one of:

> ```
> LAYERS: Input layers
>
> Parameter type:   QgsProcessingParameterMultipleLayers
>
> Accepted data types:
>   - list[str]: list of layer IDs
>   - list[str]: list of layer names
>   - list[str]: list of layer sources
>   - list[QgsMapLayer]
>   - QgsProperty
> ```

Check `processing.algorithmHelp("native:mergevectorlayers")` for more details.

So, change in your code

```py
processing.run("native:mergevectorlayers",
{'LAYERS': "[" + fileliststring + "]", 
'CRS':None,
'OUTPUT': path + "merged.shp",})
```

to

```py
processing.run("native:mergevectorlayers",
{'LAYERS': filelist,
'CRS':None,
'OUTPUT': path + "merged.shp",})
```

Comment: Was just on my way back to say this was the problem. Thanks for illustrating!